# Python: char capitalization one-by-one

Tags: python

Trying to write a program which is to take a string as input and replace it’s chars with capitalized ones one by one, printing how far it got at each iteration:

```
>>> house
House
HOuse
HOUse
HOUSe
HOUSE
```

After many hours of banging the head in this wall, i have produced a code which is likely way off, and feels like a dead end:

```
inp = input()
temp = []

for x in inp:
    if x != x.isupper():
        x = x.upper()
        temp.append(x)

        for y in inp:
            if y != y.isupper():
                y = y.upper()

                if y not in temp:
                    y = y.lower()
                    temp.append(y)
    break

print(temp)

<<< House
```

Essentially, all this does is capitalizing the first letter and adding the remaining ones. The idea was to put this loop in a function and run it for the len of the input. But i am realizing that this is probably not the right path from the very beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need only one `for`-loop:

```
for i in range(1, len(w)+1):
    print w[:i].upper()+w[i:]
```

Comment: This works great! But i understand why i wasn’t able to produce this code, as i do find it hard to follow.
How would it look if the iteration went backwards, producing
`housE
houSE
hoUSE`
and so on? I tried with reversed() and playing with, for instance, (len(text), -1, -1), but it doesn’t produce the output above.

Comment: ADD: managed – `reversed()` was to be used together with switching places of the 2 parts inside `print` :)　Accepting as solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "house"

l = [s[:i].upper() + s[i:] for i in range(len(s)+1)]

print l #['house', 'House', 'HOuse', 'HOUse', 'HOUSe']
```

Comment: I like those one linears using generators. But I guess OP will probably take time to understand.